# ByteBuddy - unable to intercept static method from superclass

Tags: java, android, byte-buddy

I'm working on command line tool for Android (think of am), trying to utilize the power of ByteBuddy to stub the static method **getApplicationContext** defined in android.security.KeyStore

However - the method seem to be invisible to ByteBuddy **getDeclaredMethods** when subclassing the android.security.KeyStore and hence it is unable to intercept it.

When using **getMethods** from the reflection API i'm able to list the method.

```java
            Class AndroidKeyStore = Class.forName("android.security.KeyStore");
            Method[] keyStoreMethods =  new ByteBuddy()
                      .with(TypeValidation.DISABLED)
                      .subclass(AndroidKeyStore, ConstructorStrategy.Default.IMITATE_SUPER_CLASS)
                      .name("KeyStoreMasker")
                      .method(ElementMatchers.named("getApplicationContext"))
                      .intercept(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE)
                      .make()
                      .load(getClass().getClassLoader(),
                            new AndroidClassLoadingStrategy
                            .Injecting(new File("/data/app/cmdutil")))
                      .getLoaded()
                      .getDeclaredMethods();
            for(i = 0; i < keyStoreMethods .length; i++) {
                System.out.println("method = " + keyStoreMethods[i].toString());
            }
```

When running the above, I was expecting to have a single method - **getApplicationContext** in the subclass. However the subclass doesn't contain any methods.

Replacing the call to **getDeclaredMethods** by **getMethods** I'm able to list all public method of the superclass.

By replacing the intercepted method to a non-static one (for example "state"), i'm able to list the method using ByteBuddy's **getDeclaredMethods** function:

> Number of declared methods in keyStoreMethods: 2
>
> method = public android.security.KeyStore$State AndroidKeyStoreMasker.state()
>
> method = public android.security.KeyStore$State AndroidKeyStoreMasker.state(int)

So my final conclusion is that ByteBuddy (or my usage case with ByteBuddy) has some issue with static method visibility.

Reference to android.security.KeyStore.java:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/keystore/java/android/security/KeyStore.java

Any help would be much appreaciated.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a `subclass`, Byte Buddy is only able to intercept methods directly declared by a subclass or virtual methods of super classes. This is how the JVM works, `static` methods are dispatched directly on the receiver.

Byte Buddy is capable of redefining and retransforming existing classes, too, but this requires a Java agent which is not available on Android. Therefore, I am afraid that you need to find a non-static hook point to accomplish what you are trying. Alternatively, have a look at the `MemberSubstitution` where you can redirect such calls from your code. This also requires a retransformation but since it happens in your code, you can use Byte Buddy's build plugin.

Comment: Thanks for responding.


As I don't have any option for none static hook point I went for your second offering - using bytebuddy's build plugin for Maven.

But - since the method from the called class is not defined in my code and referenced by reflection, I don't see how to make use of your suggestion.

The `android.security.KeyStore` class is not available on build time. 
So - what did I miss ?

Comment: You'd need to substitute the calls in your code invoking the methods in question. This can be done in build time.